# My list will be empty when POST the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have some problem with the MVC, I'll try to describe. I have 2 class in my model.

```
public class ApplicationPermissionVM
    {
        public ApplicationPermission Permission { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

public class RoleAndPermissonsModel
{
        //Constructor skipped

        public ApplicationRole ApplicationRole { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ApplicationPermissionVM> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

The second model is the main model, and I initialize the model in controller. The ApplicationRole is null and I have got 19 element in the list. When I POST the form the ApplicationRole member will be created, but the Permissions list will be empty so will lost all selection. If anyone knows what is the problem please write to me.
Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewRole()
{
    _model = new RoleAndPermissonsModel();
    return View(_model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewRole(RoleAndPermissonsModel newRole)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var id = _applicationRoleService.AddNewRole(newRole.ApplicationRole);
        _applicationRoleService.AssignPermissionsToRole(newRole.SelectedItems, id);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
@model EO.Core.WebUI.Models.RoleAndPermissonsModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewRole", "PermissionRole", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmNewRole" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ApplicationRole</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationRole.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicationRole.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationRole.Name)
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsSelected)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model.Permissions)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.IsSelected)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Permission.Name);
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Where are your view and controller?

Comment: Sorry,I forgot it but I resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need manually to loop through the list and output it like

```
<input type="text" 
       id="Permissions[0].IsSelected" 
       name="Permissions[0].IsSelected" value="" />
```

so, change your code to:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Permissions.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" 
                   id="Permissions[@(i)].IsSelected" 
                   name="Permissions[@(i)].IsSelected" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" 
                   id="Permissions[@(i)].Permission.Name" 
                   name="Permissions[@(i)].Permission.Name" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

because you have an object inside your type `Permissions` remember to initialiate it or you will get a null reference.

```
public class RoleAndPermissonsModel
{
    public RoleAndPermissonsModel() {
        this.Permissions = new List<ApplicationPermissionVM>();
    }

    public ApplicationRole ApplicationRole { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationPermissionVM> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

or you can easily create a `ViewModel` instead and use that to interlink your Model to your View.

**Note:** I do wonder, if your list is always null (as you are passing an empty/null list) why are you looping through `Model.Permissions` ?

---

In order to do the "EDIT" view, the loop code should be:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Permissions.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" 
                   @(Permissions[i].IsSelected ? "checked='checked'" : "")
                   id="Permissions[@(i)].IsSelected" 
                   name="Permissions[@(i)].IsSelected" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" 
                   id="Permissions[@(i)].Permission.Name" 
                   name="Permissions[@(i)].Permission.Name"
                   value="@(Permissions[i].Permission.Name)" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

all you need to add is `checked` to the checkbox if it's selected and fill the permission name to the other input.

Comment: THX. It works perfectly! I have a constructor too, but I forgot to write here so my permission is not null. Is there any other solution to display my Model.Permissions without looping?

Comment: Just another question, the checkbox need to set up the Model.Permissions[i].IsSelected property. What can I do?

Comment: did you read my note? you are doing `_model = new RoleAndPermissonsModel(); return View(_model);` you are setting an empty object, the list will always empty ... no?

Comment: I have added the **edit** view loop code for your information.

Comment: Thx. Sorry for missunderstanding, I tried to told you that my list is not empty :) My constructor was skipped from this example but is exist, so the Permission list is filled from database, and I would like to create an UI where user can select which permission assign to the Role. And the IsSelected property will says form me in controller which permission was selected. :) Thank you for your help it was really helpful ;)